# When i select , only one column is checked without duplicates

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have a 2 table like this:

```sql
first table
+------------+---------------+--------+  
| pk         | user_one      |user_two|   
+------------+---------------+--------+  
second table
+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------+   
| pk         | sender        |receiver|fk of firsttable|content        |
+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

First and second table have one to many(1:N) relations.

There are many records in second table:

```
| pk    | sender|receiver|fk of firsttable|content           |
|120    |car224 |car223  |1               |test message1 to 223
|121    |car224 |car223  |1               |test message2 to 223
|122    |car224 |car225  |21              |test message1 to 225
|123    |car224 |car225  |21              |test message2 to 225
|124    |car224 |car225  |21              |test message3 to 225
|125    |car224 |car225  |21              |test message4 to 225
```

I need to find if `fk` has the same value and I want the row with the largest `pk`.

I've changed the above column name to make it easier to understand.

Here is the actual `sql` I've tried so far:

```
select *
  from (select rownum rn,
               mr.mrno,
               mr.user_one,
               mr.user_two,
               m.mno,
               m.content
          from tbl_messagerelation mr,
               tbl_message m 
          where (mr.user_one = 'car224' or
                 mr.user_two='car224') and
                m.rowid in (select max(rowid)
                              from tbl_message
                              group by m.mno) and
                rownum <= 1*20)
  where rn > (1-1) * 20
```

And this is the result:

```
+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|  rn     |  mrno | user_one | user_two | mno(pk of second table) |        content       |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
|       1 |     1 | car224   | car223   |                     125 | test message4 to 225 |
|       2 |    21 | car224   | car225   |                     125 | test message4 to 225 |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------------+
```

My desired result is something like this:

```
+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  fk     |  sender | receiver | pk of second table | content              |
+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+
|       1 | car224  | car223   |                121 | test message2 to 223 |
|      21 | car224  | car223   |                125 | test message4 to 225 |
+---------+---------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: If you want to select columns from one table only(as in your desired result), why are you joining the 2 tables in your query?

Comment: I was wrong. The result I want can be a single table. The first table, however, has much less data than the second table, so I thought it would take less time to fetch the data.

Comment: Sure. Then go ahead and and try my second query in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table description when compared to your query is confusing me. However, what I could understand was that you are probably looking for `row_number()`.

An important advice is to use standard explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than outdated `a,b` syntax for joins. Join keys were not clear to me and you may replace it appropriately in your final query.

```
select * from
(
select mr.*, m.*, row_number() over ( partition by m.fk order by m.pk desc ) as rn
from tbl_messagerelation mr join  tbl_message m on mr.? = m.? 
) where rn =1
```

Or perhaps  you don't need that join at all

```
select * from
(
select  m.*, row_number() over ( partition by m.fk order by m.pk desc ) as rn
 from  tbl_message m 
) where rn =1
```

Comment: I dont think you need 1st table for desire result

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : Yes, it is possible. I looked at the OP's query where they're selecting columns from both tables and hence kept it that way, but the desired result has columns only from one table. As I said, it's confusing. Let OP clarify, I'll edit my answer.